# Router does not use truck weight parameters for calculations

Tags: heremaps, heremaps-android-sdk

Android here sdk premium version 3.18.5

Here sdk is not using weight parameter or I'm using it in a wrong way.
My base route settings:

```
routePlan.routeOptions.routeType = RouteOptions.Type.FASTEST
routePlan.routeOptions.transportMode = RouteOptions.TransportMode.TRUCK
```

I checked different combinations of `truckLimitedWeight` and `truckWeightPerAxle` parameters without luck. Router still returns routes through the road with a 5t or a 3.5 weight restriction. Is there any other setting that should be set to achive weight restrictions aware truck routing?

Comment: Maybe related:
when i use `TruckRestrictionsChecker.getTruckRestrictions(roadElement)` on road element  that have weight restrictions it returns me correct restriction, but when im using `TruckRestrictionsChecker.getTruckRestrictions(roadElement, options)` with options used to route calculation i get no restrictions at all on that roads.
My options:

routeType = RouteOptions.Type.FASTEST
transportMode = RouteOptions.TransportMode.TRUCK
truckTrailersCount = 1
truckLimitedWeight = 40f
truckAxleCount = 2
truckWeightPerAxle = 20f
truckType = RouteOptions.TruckType.TRUCK